# how can i manually input a value in a private variable

Tags: java

i have a problem that i cant input a value in private variable 
how can i make a `setNama` method to edit it

**Code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class customer {
    private String nama;
    private String password;
    private int saldo;

    public void setNama(String nama) {
        this.nama = nama;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Nama akun : ");
        nama = input.nextLine();
        input.close();
    }

    public String getNama() {
        return nama;
    }
}
```

i think it was correct

```
public class openBioskop {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        customer akun = new customer();
        akun.setNama(String nama);
        System.out.println("nama akun anda : "+akun.getNama());
    }

}
```

but i cant access this `setNama` method from main, an `Exception` is `thrown`. Can you explain what is the problem?

Comment: Please include the error message / stacktrace, and actual vs expected result. [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove this block from your `setNama`(...) method.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Nama akun : ");
nama = input.nextLine();
input.close();
```

And to set your method correctly like:

```
akun.setNama("Jhon");
```

And if you want to use the Scanner for having input you can write it in main method like  below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    customer akun = new customer();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Nama akun : ");
    String  nama = input.nextLine();
    akun.setNama(nama);
    System.out.println("nama akun anda : "+akun.getNama());
}
```

Comment: I did not down-vote it, but possible problems are your grammar mistakes and unstructured code.

Comment: Ok possible mistakes in my grammar but the code is good, strange.

Comment: Problems: There is no SetName method. "Correctly" instead of "corretelly". Instead of "like." use "like:". "Want to use" instead of "wont to use". Instead of "below." use "below:". And structure your code, my eyes are bleeding. I repeat, I did not down-vote your answer, but I cannot upvote it if you do not fix these issues.

Comment: Two issues remained, I fixed them myself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96381/discussion-between-abdelhak-and-lajos-arpad).

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the method this way:

```
akun.setNama(String nama);
```

which is syntactically incorrect, you need to pass a variable which exists (`nama` does not exist in this scope) and you should not specify its type of String when you call the method.

Also, you are reading the value inside the method with

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

which is not quite a good idea. Suggestion:

```
public class openBioskop {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        customer akun = new customer();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Nama akun : ");
        nama = input.nextLine();
        akun.setNama();
        input.close();
        System.out.println("nama akun anda : "+akun.getNama());
    }

}
```

and

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class customer {
    private String nama;
    private String password;
    private int saldo;

    public void setNama(String nama) {
        this.nama = nama;
    }

    public String getNama() {
        return nama;
    }
}
```